# Looping certain frames

Tags: animation, modifiers, loop, looping

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to go about this and so far have come up with nothing. I'm trying to create a loop out of a number of keyframes in my animation sequence of 130 keyframes. This loop would leave out certain keyframes, say the first two and the last four. I've tried using the cycles modifier in the graph editor but still can't get it down.

Comment: Hi, could you please give an example of what you are trying to do, and maybe link the blend file? It's not very clear what you are asking for here.

Comment: does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57394/how-to-specify-frames-for-%D0%A1ycles-modifier-in-f-curve-editor